# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT after installing nginx with Webinoly

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, nginx

I installed Webinoly as I had already done on other ubuntu servers, but now I have this problem, when I enter only the server IP, the default Nginx page appears, but when I type the site that I added with Webinoly, the error "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" appears. I already checked the DNS and even added SSL with certbot, and I know that if the DNS are not correct it is not possible, so the problems are probably not DNS

I ran these commands for the Firewall and it still didn't work

`sudo iptables -I INPUT 6 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT sudo netfilter-persistent save`

I also released ports 80,443 and range 23-90